# How does one have the Jupyter variable pane in VS Code to load the variables in session?

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter

I was trying out VS Code with Jupyter but the variables never finish loading in the variable pane:

[image]

this is some info by my env:

```
Environment data
VS Code version: Version: 1.41.1
Extension version (available under the Extensions sidebar):2020.2.59126-dev
OS and version: macOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57)
Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base':conda)
Type of virtual environment used (N/A | venv | virtualenv | conda | ...): conda
Relevant/affected Python packages and their versions: Jupyter
```

Did anyone else have this issue? Anyone know how to fix it? Is this really a bug or maybe just a problem with my set up?

---

Related sources:

- gitissue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9773
- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/eub7n2/how_does_one_have_the_jupyter_variable_pane_in_vs/
- quora: https://qr.ae/TDT92y

Answer (score 1):

From [the gitissue suggestion from the developers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9773#issuecomment-578831369):

> Can you try updating your build?

I couldn't find an easy way to do this except by right clicking on the gear icon for the python extension.

[image]

Then clicked install another version and clicked the most current one.

[image]

That made things work.

---

Enable Auto updating extensions:

With the command palette, one can also turn on automatic updates for extensions. Simply do:

`Command + shift + p`

then type:

`updating extensions`

and select

`enable auto updating extensions`

not sure if it will avoid this issue in the future but its worth a try.